# Python + mypy + mixin = has no attribute error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mixins, mypy

I have Vscode + mypy error in the UI interface: "EngineMixin" has no attribute "engine"
for the next Mixin class

```
class EngineMixin:
    def prepare_start(self):
        self.engine.start()

    def prepare_stop(self):
        self.engine.stop()

    def __str__(self):
        output = super().__str__()
        output += f'\n{self.__class__.__name__} characteristics. Engine [{self.engine}]' # noqa
        return output
```

In fact, this error is shown only in Vscode UI interface.  When I run mypy in cli, there are no errors.
In general, I understand why this error appears, but is there any way to supress it in vscode?

Edited (added screen):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Why do you think this error appears?  Why only in VSCode? 
What is referring to this code?

Comment: Hi @Steve, as far as I understand, mypy plugin doesn't see declaration of this property in this exactly class and says "no attribute". And it sounds logically.
But I am confused why it is only in Vscode.
- mypy itself in terminal doesn't give this error
- and Pycharm also keeps  silence.  


I realize, that Pychaem is my more "clever".  So if it is ok for Vscode, I am fine too. But maybe there is a way to supress it

Comment: Is this all your code? I copied and pasted it in my .py file and it worked well, no such warnings.  I'm using python3.9, languageserver is Pylance. Can you post the full screenshot that includes code and error in VS Code?

Comment: Hi @MollyWang, yes, that is all the code. I've edited the question and added the screenshot.

Comment: Try to run this code in a new workspace.

Comment: I see the same error in VSCode. My mixins are a way to break apart a large class and depend on methods and attributes that will only exist in the final subclass that inherits from all mixins. The code itself runs fine despite the errors shown in VSCode.

Answer (score 13):

For mixins that refer to the class they're being mixed into, you can use a type stub to let mypy know that `self.engine` is expected to exist

```py
class EngineMixin:

    # Like this
    engine: Engine

    def prepare_start(self):
        self.engine.start()

    def prepare_stop(self):
        self.engine.stop()

    def __str__(self):
        output = super().__str__()
        output += f'\n{self.__class__.__name__} characteristics. Engine [{self.engine}]' # noqa
        return output
```

Comment: +1. Relevant documentation: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols